# Iterating through selected values from a multiple select input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to iterate through the selected values from a multiple select box and check them against a string, returning false as soon as a match is not found.  First I tried:

```
var exampleString = "example";
var mySelections = $("#mySelect option:selected");
for (selection in mySelections) {
    if (exampleString.indexOf(mySelections[selection].text()) === -1) {
        return false; 
    };
};
```

This code gives me an error, however: "text is not a function".  I am given to understand that this is because using the index gets the option object itself, not wrapped in jQuery, and it is jQuery that provides the text() method.

I tried an alternative version using the each function:

```
var result = $("#mySelect option:selected").each(function () {
    if (exampleString.indexOf($( this ).text()) === -1) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

However, I do not understand the result I'm getting.  I naively assumed that my variable result would be set to false or true, but it seems to just [return the objects being iterated over](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).  Is there any way to access the results of those string comparisons short of creating a global variable that gets set to true or false inside the function?

**Edited to add:** upon request, here's the relevant html:

```
<select multiple="" class="filterSelect" id="mySelect" style="display: none;">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Change `mySelections[selection]` to `mySelections.eq(selection)` and see if your logic changes, since `eq()` returns a jQuery object

Comment: This is difficult to answer without HTML. Would you please provide that? 
Have you tried `$(this).val()` instead?

Comment: Thank you, @Taplar! What a simple solution. I do not have enough reputation to accept or even upvote your answer, but I appreciate it.

@HolayMolay I have updated the post to include the relevant html, just in case it helps others reading this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do (I'm not a jQuery user any more):

```js
let testStr = "dd";

document.getElementById('sel').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const values = []
  for (let i=0; i<e.target.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
    values.push(e.target.selectedOptions[i].value);
  }
  console.log(!values.includes(testStr));
  return !values.includes(testStr);
})
```

```html
<select id="sel" multiple>
  <option value="aa">aa</option>
  <option value="bb">bb</option>
  <option value="cc">cc</option>
  <option value="dd">dd</option>
  <option value="ee">ee</option>
</select>
```